# Every comma separated CSV value to new row in PhpMyadmin

Tags: database, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a csv like "one,two,three,four" and a mysql table with only id (auto) and name.

I want to import the csv like this

ID  Name

1   One

2   Two

3   Three

4   Four

Answer (score 0):

I suggest modifying your source file so that each entry is on a new line. You can accomplish that with almost any text editor, stream editors like sed or awk, or scripting languages like Python or Perl.

One such way is with tr:

```
tr , '\n' < infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

Then in phpMyAdmin, the default import settings should be fine except you need to tell it to insert only to your `Name` column, by putting the name of the column in the "Column names" text field:

[image: Import dialog]